# Training neural network on a sequence of moves

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I've been playing with neural networks just out of personal curiosity and wanting to learn. So far, it's been a success. I've written a code for one from scratch, with backpropagation for training, and trained it to play tic-tac-toe (outputs 3x3 matrix with highest value in an open spot being played). It's based off of [this example](http://colinfahey.com/neural_network_with_back_propagation_learning/neural_network_with_back_propagation_learning.html) except designed to allow multiple hidden layers.

The training data is a randomly generated mid-game situation and to supervise the learning, I wrote by hand an algorithm for ranking the possible moves to use as the "correct" answers. After training it a couple thousand times, it works pretty well at making the best move and can play a whole game pretty well (favors opening in center, while perfect game you take corner, but whatever).

Anyways, that's all well and good, but for the training, it required me to create a specific algorithm to rank each move for any given play, which was easy enough cause tic-tac-toe is very simple, but this isn't practical. My next milestone, would be to be able to train it just based on winning or losing the game. However, this requires it to remember a sequence of moves, then backpropagate the training not just through the neurons but a sequence of moves after the game is finished. I just have no idea where to start, even being pointed in the right direction would help.

Comment: I guess there are many approaches; one is a field called Reinforcement Learning, in which a common model is Markov Decision Process (MDP): https://www.google.co.il/search?q=markov+decision+process+for+tic+tac+tow&ei=ZgqLVd2OIYSdsgG6gI34CQ#q=markov+decision+process+for+tic+tac+toe

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for but I couldn't get my search terms right to find it.